# Using a REST web service to post a CSV file

Tags: java, rest, api, web-services, post

I have this method to connect to my webservice (REST API)

```
public static void getHttpCon() throws Exception{

    String tokenUrl = AppPropertiesService.getProperty( URL_TOKEN );
    String username = AppPropertiesService.getProperty( USERNAME );
    String password = AppPropertiesService.getProperty( PASSWORD );

    String POST_PARAMS = "username="+username+"&password="+password+"&lang=fr&grant_type=password&client_id=apiclient";
    URL obj = new URL(tokenUrl);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
            "Basic Base64_encoded_clientId:clientSecret");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    // For POST only - START
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    // For POST only - END

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("POST request not worked");
    }
}
```

I want to know how can i `POST`a CSV File .

Should I do it directly in my method above ?

Do I have to create a new method by recovering the connection token from my method above?

My API ULR is `POST /api/{id}/csv`